# Error trying to split image colors: numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'

Tags: matplotlib, tensorflow, keras, image-recognition

This is my python code:

```
from PIL import Image

labels = ['airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer','dog','frog','horse','ship','truck']

from keras.datasets import cifar10

(X_train, Y_train), (X_test,y_test) = cifar10.load_data()



index = int(input('Enter an image index: '))
display_image = X_train[index]
display_label = Y_train[index][0]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

red_image = Image.fromarray(display_image)
red,green,blue = red_image.split()

plt.imshow(red, cmap="Reds")
plt.show()

print(labels[display_label])
```

Thats the error returned

> File "/Users/mcarvalho/PycharmProjects/SimpleImageRecognition/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 419, in _make_image
>       if A.mask.shape == A.shape:
>   AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'

Comment: I have the same problem after updating numpy and matplot lib to the recent versions. Still, have no idea what happens there...

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but, could you solved this issue? And if you do, how?

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be fixed in matplotlib 2.2.2 also:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib --upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a bug in matplotlib. You can downgrade your matplotlib to version 2.0.0, and then it will work. At least it works for me. To downgrade matplotlib you have to run

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib==2.0.0
```

Hope it will help you!